# is $P(x) \to \forall x P(x)$ satisfiable

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, satisfiability

I need to prove that this formula  $P(x) \to \forall x P(x)$ is satisfiable.
Can I say for example that x is even number ?

Comment: The task must be to show that _no matter what_ $P$ is (and no matter which interpretation you're working in), there's an $x$ that satisfies the formula. In particular $P$ may not have anything to do with even numbers, so thinking about even numbers is not likely to be successul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $P(x)$ is true for all $x$, then $\forall x P(x)$ and the implication is true.

If $P(x)$ if false for some $x=x_0$, then $P(x_0)\implies\forall x P(x)$ is true because $P(x_0)$ is false.

Comment: But if we say that $P(x)$ is true when x is an even number and $\forall x P(x)$ is false, then for example: $P(4) \to \forall P(x)$ implication is false. Or I am thinking wrong?

Comment: @user2965303, $\text{false}\implies\text{anything}$, $\text{anything}\implies\text{true}$. In your example the implication is false, but $P(3)\implies\forall P(x)$ is true because...